# Rails No route matches [GET] "/accounts/sign_out

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

So, I stubbled on this error which seemed old enough and no recent update. The answers I found turned around [routes missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555793/why-the-error-no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out): (of course), [Javascript includes missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508574/no-route-matches-get-user-sign-out-rails-5) and finally the config edit to send the delete call into a get.

Nothing worked for me except changing the config of devise which to me seemed like a patch. Plus my button worked previously without major modifications...

My code looked like this :

```
    document.toggleMenu = function(e) {
      var menu = document.getElementById('menu-content');
      menu.style.visibility = menu.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    document.closeMenu = function() {
      document.getElementById('menu-content').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```

The function closeMenu() is called onClick from the body.

```
    <div class="profileBtn profile-menu-icon" onclick="toggleMenu(event)">Mon profil</div>
              <ul id="menu-content" class="shadowed-menu" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
                <li class="centered-div">
                  <div>
                    <div class="profile-menu-icon profile-inside-menu-icon header-text">
                      Mon profil
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-text">
                      <%=current_account.email%>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>
                    <div class="menu-text">
                      Modifier mon profil
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-text">
                      <%=current_account.profile.first_name%> <%=current_account.profile.last_name%> (<%=current_account.profile.registration_number%>)
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to 'Se déconnecter', destroy_account_session_path, method: "delete", class: "button button-primary" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails transform the [GET] "/accounts/sign_out" into a [DELETE] "/accounts/sign_out" using Javascript, the onclick="event.stopPropagation();" stops it from working properly.

I replaced

```
<ul id="menu-content" class="shadowed-menu" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
```

with

```
<ul id="menu-content" class="shadowed-menu" onclick="stopPropagation(event)">
```

```
  document.stopPropagation = function(e){
    var senderId = e.path[0].id;
    if(senderId != "disconnect"){
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

that makes the event generated by Rails from the button continue to bubble up and work as intended.